# How to get the maximum value from an array of array of tuples in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, tuples, react-typescript

I currently have data stored for a line chart with an array of another array of tuples, so for example `[[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]]]`. What's the best way to get the maximum Y value across all lines from this structure?

I could create a helper function to get the maximum Y from an array, and then create a helper function to call the first helper function while looping through every line's data. Is there a much simpler way that I'm missing here? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the expected output? Please include your code attempt in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward take on this using `Array.map`:

```
const tuples = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [2, 3],
]

const max = Math.max(...tuples.map((tuple) => Math.max(...tuple)))

console.log(max)  // 4
```

This is essentially what you described in your question; the "helper function" is the inlined arrow function `(tuple) => Math.max(...tuple))`, which finds the maximum value in each tuple when mapped over `tuples`.

Unfortunately, `Math.max` doesn't take arrays directly, so you need to unpack the array in the call using the spread operator `...`.

Note that the `Array.map` usage is equivalent to the `for` loops you suggest in your question, just more compact and expressive to type out.

Whether you agree that this is "simpler" is, I suppose, up to you...